# Instance of MongoDB server shut down when creating an AMI image

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was trying to clone an instance of a MongoDB server on EC2. When I selected the instance, and did 'create image', it shut down our MongoDB server completely. The IP has not changed, and we are unable to connect to it. I tried to reboot the server, as well as start it and end it. The clone of the AMI has not been touched. How am I able to get the server back up?

When we try to start the server, the terminal just says 'failed.'

Answer (score 0):

We need some more information about this to give the exact solution. Please provide how you are taking the AMI. But we can assume what might be happened.

As per AWS, the `SNAPSHOT and AMI are not consistent`. So to make it as a consistent, they provide an option to reboot while taking the AMI. If you are going to take the AMI from the AWS console they will be a CheckBox to prevent it.

If you are using any Lambda or CLI tools just disable the Reboot option.